# How to get latitude and longitude passing pincode in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

How to get latitude and longitude by passing parameter as pincode.I have form with pincode. when entered some pincode number into text box,then how to get latitude and longitude.but not passing address how to get latitude and longitude only passing pincode as a parameter.

tried like this it's not working.can any one help me

**java**

```
final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                    pincode = pincode1.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(pincode, 1);
                        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                            Address address = addresses.get(0);
                            // Use the address as needed
                            String message = String.format("Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f",
                                    address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // Display appropriate message when Geocoder services are not available
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to geocode zipcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // handle exception
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

You can make `http Get request for the following link`.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:638701&sensor=false

Demo result:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "638701",
               "short_name" : "638701",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tamil Nadu",
               "short_name" : "TN",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Tamil Nadu 638701, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.12035,
                  "lng" : 77.7041998
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 10.9142493,
                  "lng" : 77.4507146
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 11.0179181,
               "lng" : 77.58486649999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.12035,
                  "lng" : 77.7041998
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 10.9142493,
                  "lng" : 77.4507146
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJl35xdEKfqTsRcr8NKDs37OM",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

change the postal code Element According to your requirements

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1#JSON